# How to Rotate vector

Tags: c#, vector, rotation, var

I've been searching on tons of forums but nothing to work with (or understand). 
So i have this

```
public void OnFinishCasting(Champion owner, Spell spell, Unit target)
    {
        var current = new Vector2(owner.X, owner.Y);
        var to = Vector2.Normalize(new Vector2(spell.X, spell.Y) - current);
        var range = to * 1150;
        var trueCoords = current + range;
```

And i will explain to you what it does.
When i Press the Q button it shots a projectile in the mouse direction , What i need is to make another projectile and shot it in another direction like a cone or something , no matter where it goes , just rotate it how i like.
How to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you are saying:

> make another projectile and shot it in another direction ..., no
>   matter where it goes

I will just add some random value to the X & Y on

```
new Vector2(spell.X + intRndX, spell.Y + intRndY)
```

## update based on follow up comment

Try this:

```
public static class Vector2Extensions
{
    public static Vector2 Rotate(this Vector2 v, double degrees)
    {
        return new Vector2(
            (float)(v.X * Math.Cos(degrees) - v.Y * Math.Sin(degrees)),
            (float)(v.X * Math.Sin(degrees) + v.Y * Math.Cos(degrees))
        );
    }
}
```

That will add an extension to the Vector2 class and you can call :

```
trueCoords.Rotate(Math.PI/90)
```

to get the new vector

Comment: Oh well , let me rectify , i formulated the sentence wrong.
Make another projectile , but shot it like 90 degrees difference between the original one (and the original one is shooting where the mouse is )

Comment: I think there might be more hidden **captchas** can you add your project to GitHub and paste a link here?

Comment: Here is the complet CS file of the projectile 
https://github.com/LeagueSandbox/LeagueSandbox-Default/blob/indev/Champions/Ezreal/Q.cs

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for helping me out , but , im a monkey in C# , can you show me where to put this code you gave me ? Thanks again !

Comment: Sure will do a commit on my fork: https://github.com/heldersepu/LeagueSandbox-Default

Comment: ...and Here is the commit: https://github.com/heldersepu/LeagueSandbox-Default/commit/0d3e94dddc5a8c4f4753c79667e59a9d4ccf0f91